# Conclude XML files with same data using Regex

Tags: xml, regex, ant

i have a little problem with useing regular expressions in ANT. I have two XML files which have a strcture like that:

XML file 1:

```
<testtag id="2234">
<blabla>data</blabla>
    </testtag>
```

XML file 2:

```
<testtag id="2234">
    <blabla>data2</blabla>
        </testtag>
```

Now i need an regular expression for ANT which selects all data between the testtags which have the same id and put them together in one final XML file.
I tried a few differnt regular expression but nothing worked..

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regular expressions to parse XML.

If you want to know why, see for example:

[Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg?rq=1)

[Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la?lq=1)

and of course the classic:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine you'd do it, is with this:

`<testtag id="2234"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/testtag>`